# display session timeout interval in sinatra

Tags: ruby, timeout, sinatra

I have a sinatra (ruby) based web application which is used to control the workflow for end users.

It appears there is one task that can take so long that the session is `nil` at the time it is ready to perform the next step. It results in an error message and the task is not completed properly.

I want to increase the session timeout (if it is possible at all). But first, since I have not explicitly set it, I want to know the actual value of the timeout interval. Is there a way to access and print that?

Comment: Sinatra doesn’t time out. It’s your Web server that does. What web server are you using?

Comment: It is a standalone application, run from the command line. That is probably a rack application, but I'm not sure.